# Views return NullPointerException in onBindViewHolder in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, listadapter, android-recyclerview

I want to build custom adapter for RecyclerView but when I set Text or set value for any view it's return NullPointerException. I don't why. Tried many solution but all of them didn't work.
My adapter:

```
public class HistoryViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ApplicationDataManager> arrayOfHistoryManagerClass;


    public HistoryViewAdapter(ArrayList<ApplicationDataManager> HistoryClassArray) {

        this.arrayOfHistoryManagerClass = HistoryClassArray;

    }


    @Override
    public HistoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.history_translate_include, parent, false);

        return new HistoryViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HistoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ApplicationDataManager managerClass = arrayOfHistoryManagerClass.get(position);
            holder.NonTranslatedWord.setText(managerClass.getNonTranslatedText());
            holder.TranslatedWord.setText(managerClass.GetTranslatedText());
            holder.isFavoret.setChecked(managerClass.GetFavoredStat());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayOfHistoryManagerClass.size();
    }



}
```

My ViewHolder (I tried FindViewByid instead of Butterknife but it gives the same Exception):

```
public class HistoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // Defining a TextView
    @InjectView(R.id.translated_word)
    protected  TextView TranslatedWord;
    // Defining a TextView
    @InjectView(R.id.non_translated_word)
    protected  TextView NonTranslatedWord;
    @InjectView(R.id.history_checkBox)
    protected  CheckBox isFavoret;

    public HistoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //injecting views
        ButterKnife.inject(itemView);

    }
}
```

Finally MyFragment:

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {
    @InjectView(R.id.history_recyclerview)
    RecyclerView historyRecycler;
    HistoryViewAdapter historyViewAdapter;
    ArrayList<ApplicationDataManager> listDataManager;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_translate_include, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        historyRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listDataManager = new ArrayList<ApplicationDataManager>();
        listDataManager.add(new ApplicationDataManager("Test","Test",true,"Engilsh","arabic"));
        listDataManager.add(new ApplicationDataManager("Test","Test",false,"Engilsh","arabic"));

        historyViewAdapter = new HistoryViewAdapter(listDataManager);

        historyRecycler.setAdapter(historyViewAdapter);


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
My logcat:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at list.adapter.HistoryViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(HistoryViewAdapter.java:42)
            at list.adapter.HistoryViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(HistoryViewAdapter.java:18)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4138)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3448)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1306)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1531)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1705)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1559)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1468)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1705)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1559)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.j
```

My history_translate_include.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/history_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/translate_history"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/history_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/history_textview"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/history_textview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/history_textview"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post the exception and point us the line its throwing from,,

Comment: @Smit added Logcat Code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use wrong ButterKnife inject method.

Use `HistoryViewHolder` constructor below:

```
public HistoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    //This line is important
    ButterKnife.inject(this,itemView);

}
```

instead of

```
public HistoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    //injecting views
    ButterKnife.inject(itemView);

}
```

When you want to inject some views for object which contains these views but it is not `Fragment` `Activity` or `View`, you have to call method:

```
 ButterKnife.inject(Object,View);
```

And additionally you use `history_translate_include` in onCreateViewHolder method, you should use there layout for single item which contains view with these ids : `translated_word, non_translated_word, history_checkBox`

```
@Override
public HistoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.layout_for_single_item, parent, false);

    return new HistoryViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Comment: Tested it..but it doesn't work.. I also had test to use findViewById but gived me the same exception.

Comment: Could you post history_translate_include layout?

Comment: Added. check it please.

Comment: Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes, let me test this. Thanks

Comment: I suppose that you create some layout which contains translated_word, non_translated_word, history_checkBox ids you have to use it instead of  history_translate_include in onCreateViewHolder

Comment: thanks for help.. I had solved it..check the my Answer.. and Thanks you again :)

Comment: I check them but the exception was in the xml file not in java..any way thanks for help :)

Comment: But your LogCat says something different. Your ViewHolder shouldn't work proper for your solution. It is strange for me...

Comment: If I my solution was helpful for you please accept it or give me upvote if not thank you anyway Good luck

Comment: Voting up requires 15 reputation, I have less than 15 .so sorry.

Comment: So maybe in the future :)

Comment: @mohamedsaber00 and additionally accept your answer to others :)

Comment: added this as accepted answer because in addiontal to don't put RecyclerView on scrollview..I forgot to put layout_for_single_item instead of history_includ...thanks alot man.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you :)